# Mailtrap API - Cannot send emails - "Unauthorized" API error

Tags: api, rest, smtp, mailtrap

I am using **[Mailtrap's SMTP](https://mailtrap.io/)** to send my development/test e-mails to a fake inbox.

Their SMTP server feature works well, but I'm now trying to implement their [API v2](https://api-docs.mailtrap.io/#post-/api/send) instead.

Every time I hit the `https://send.api.mailtrap.io/api/send` endpoint, I keep getting the following error:

> {"errors":["Unauthorized"]}

**More info**

- I have a Paid account and generated an API Token which has full Admin rights
- Only the `send.api.mailtrap.io/api/send` endpoint fails, other endpoints such as `mailtrap.io/accounts` are working
- I am getting the same error whether I use their API Doc Request testing tool or my code
- I am getting the same error message with their API v1

**cURL request used (from their API docs)**

```
curl -X POST "https://send.api.mailtrap.io/api/send" \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Api-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"to":[{"email":"john_doe@example.com","name":"John Doe"}],"from":{"email":"sales@example.com","name":"Example Sales Team"},"subject":"Your Example Order Confirmation","html":"<p>Congratulations on your order no. <strong>1234</strong>.</p>"}'
```

**Similar cURL request via PHP (same error message)**

```
<?php

$post = [];
$post['to'] = 'test@test.com';
$post['from'] = ['name' => 'Test', 'email' => 'test@test.com'];
$post['subject'] = 'Test';
$post['html'] = '<h2>This is a test</h2><p>It works!</p>';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://send.api.mailtrap.io/api/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Api-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I finally found the answer, here are my conclusions:**

- As of Today (Sep 2022), **Mailtrap's Sending API cannot be used to send e-mails to your Mailtrap Sandbox** (i.e. Fake Inbox). It can only be used to send real/production e-mails, to real users.
- If your Mailtrap account is older than a year, you will most likely be missing the "Send API" section in your account and only see the "API" section. The only solution to address that was to create a new account.
- If you still plan to use Mailtrap's Sending API (to send production e-mails), you will need to reach out to Support for some pre-configuration (This is not mentioned in the documentation) otherwise you will receive "Forbidden" from the API, without any additional details.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this and I have found the solution to your problem.

When looking at the [send documentation](https://api-docs.mailtrap.io/docs/mailtrap-api-docs/bcf61cdc1547e-send-email-message), it states that you must also include an **inbox id** in your url and also use the sandbox url.

So, if you change your url from `https://send.api.mailtrap.io/api/send` to `https://sandbox.api.mailtrap.io/api/send/1234567` then it should work - At least it did for me!

You can get the inbox id by going to the specific inbox in the webinterface and copy it from the url.